# How can I wait for the callback?

Tags: android, loops, asynchronous, android-asynctask, callback

I want to call my JSON class in a loop, always with another URL, and always pass the result into a RecyclerView. The problem is that I can't place this method into a loop because the loop won't wait for the callback... Any ideas how this could be done?

```
final JSON json = new JSON("http://1956.osaarchivum.org/api/items?collection=13&page=" + page + "&per_page=10", SzabadEuMusorokViewActivity.this);
    json.mJSONInterface = new JSONInterface() {
        @Override
        public void startActivityJSON() {
            mAdapter.add((ArrayList<Collection>) json.getCollections());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }};
```

And I want to increase always the page variable after the call is excecuted. I tried it with a lopp but it won't work.

Comment: First, show us some code you tried. Second, try to use `Handler.post()` and set an interval to `Handler` for repeated calls. It is `android.os.Handler`

Comment: I editet the question, sorry for no code at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always invoke the next call from the callback that you mention. Keep track of where in your array of URLs you are.

something like this (Code untested!)

```
class JsonFetcher {
   int _start, _end, _current;
   public JsonFetcher(int start, int end) {
      _start=start;_end=end;_current=start-1;
      fetch_next()
   }
   public void fetch_next() {
     _current += 1;
     if (_current < end)
        // Trigger your JSON fetch here and have it call fetch_next in the callback
   }
```

};

Comment: I added some code, can you please check it again?

Comment: So you are saying, I should make a method for this and always call itself with another URL?

Comment: Oh my fckn ohohoho ooooooooh it works. I cant believe it lol. Thank you so much :D . Im so dumb, I was working on this for 2 days :DD

Comment: Ludwig for president

Answer (score 0):

**this might help:**

in your asynctask add:

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
```

in preExecute() method:

```
this.dialog.setMessage("Processing..."); 
this.dialog.show();
```

in onPostExecute(Void result) method add:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```